# Appropriate flag for a non English answer (or question)

Tags: discussion, review-queues, languages, english

Which flag should I use for a non English post in reviews?

Example here

https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/6850553

Comment: I'd use Very Low Quality. In this case, because I have 10k+ reputation, I also voted to delete the post.

Comment: In this case, after a Google Translate it also looks like *Not An Answer* applies; it is a new question.

Comment: I was going to edit and translate but nothing ever makes much sense in translate

Comment: There really isn't any point in even attempting. The comments on the question suggest that the correct answer is to use `this.`, which that answer doesn't even touch upon. I cannot make heads nor tails of what it *is* saying though. It is therefor unsalvageable and should just be deleted.

Comment: "Unclear what you're asking" is what I'd choose.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

For questions, you can use "A community-specific reason" -> "Not written in English" as your close-vote/flag reason.

For answers, either "Very Low Quality" or "Not an Answer" would probably be OK too. It fits the description of either flag/close reason, since the vast majority of SO users won't be able to make any sense of it without Google Translate.

Comment: And chances that anyone can make any sense of it after Google Translate is pretty slim.